# Inserting generic parameters (not picked from a <form>) into FormData, then collecting them from servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm developing a simple web application. It uses java servlet for server-side and javascript for client-side. In the home page I have a table listing some products, where each product name is a clickable button:

```
<table border=2 id="tabellaRicerca" class="hidden">
    <tr>
        <td>Id Product</td>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>Min Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td><button>cappello con visiera</button></td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><button>anguria</button></td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Each button has an event listener that will call the following function when pressed:

```
var listenerClickProdotto = {
   handleEvent: function(e) {
    var idProdottoSelezionato = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.innerHTML; //product's id
    makeCallNoForm("POST", 'DettaglioServlet', idProdottoSelezionato, callBackFunction, false);
   }
}
```

It extracts selected product's id. Then passes it as a parameter to the makeCallNoForm.
makeCallNoForm takes the id given and tries to insert it into a FormData in order to perform an http request.

```
      
function makeCallNoForm(method, url, element, cback, reset = true) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        cback(req)
    };
    req.open(method, url);
    if (element == null) {
        req.send();
    } else {
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        var debugData = new FormData();
        debugData.set('idProdottoSelezionato', element);
        req.send(debugData);
    }
    if (element !== null && reset === true) {
        element = "";
    }
}
```

Looking at request payload seems like the FormData has been successfully added:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="idProdottoSelezionato"
4
```

But, on server side I receive no parameters:

```
@WebServlet("/DettaglioServlet")
@MultipartConfig
public class DettaglioServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int idProdottoSelezionato = -1;
        var listaParametri = request.getParameterNames(); //listaParametri is basically empty, i will add a photo showing it
idProdottoSelezionato = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idProdottoSelezionato"));//will generate error because the result of getParameter is null
idProdottoSelezionato = Integer.parseInt(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(request.getParameter("idProdottoSelezionato")));//will generate error for the same reason

                            }
}
```

This is what request.getParametersNames() returns:

[listaParametri viewed from debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdoCv.png)

I'm new to web programming and I can't understand what's wrong and why it doesn't work.
I know there are others ways to send data without using FormData (especially if I only need to send a string or number like in this case) but, for maintaining a sort of consistency through the entire application, I want to use FormData.